# How to join an int array to string in c++ separated by a dot?

Tags: c++

i have an int array

```
int arr[]={192,168,1,0};
```

What is the best way to convert it into a string separated by dots so that i can obtain the following output:

192.168.1.0

Comment: Is it a coincidence, or are you always going to print only IPv4 addresses?

Comment: What are you struggling with? You can loop through `arr` with `for (int &i : arr){ doSomethingWith(i)}`, convert `int` to `std::string` with `std::to_string` and append to a `std::vector` with `+=`. I think that's all you need for this task.

Comment: Regarding the wanted "output", is it supposed to be `192.168.0.1` (as you show) or `192.168.1.0` (as the array is arranged)? Please edit your question to either fix possibly typos or to give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is that there is no best way. You should get the confidence to develop your own style.

Assuming your array is always size 4 and your int values range from 0 to 255 (which I think is reasonable) I would do this

```
char buffer[99];
sprintf(buffer, "%d.%d.%d.%d", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
std::string ip_address(buffer);
```

Comment: `99` is kinda overkill with the constraints you assume.

Comment: `99` is easy to type and I use it for any small buffer I might need. But sure, it could be less.

Comment: Powers of 2 might be preferrable?

Comment: Using `sprintf` is exactly what came to my mind, too, and is probably the best solution unless you're already using another library (e.g., fmtlib). The only thing I would change about your code is not using a separate buffer. Since C++11, we have direct write access to the underlying buffer of a `std::string` object, so just pass that directly to `sprintf` and elide the copy.

Comment: @CodyGray - Only downside is that is that it requires a `const_cast` unless one is fortunate enough to be using C++17 too.

Comment: Fair point about the defect with `std::string::data`. I always use `&str[0]`. Nicer than a cast, and I personally find it even more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

A completely generic approach, typical C++ style:

```
template <typename Iterator>
std::string join(Iterator begin, Iterator end, char separator = '.')
{
    std::ostringstream o;
    if(begin != end)
    {
        o << *begin++;
        for(;begin != end; ++begin)
            o  << separator << *begin;
    }
    return o.str();
}
```

Could be combined with a convenience function to avoid having to get the iterators all the time:

```
template <typename Container>
std::string join(Container const& c, char separator = '.') // can pass array as reference, too
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return join(begin(c), end(c), separator);
    // not using std::... directly:
    // there might be a non-std overload that wouldn't be found if we did
}
```

The period as default separator might fit your need, but possibly is a rather bad choice for *general*, would we rather want to join with space?

If you modify the signature as follows:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Separator>
std::string join(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Separator&& separator);
```

You could use arbitrary separators, as long as supported by `operator<<` – but you lose the default separator...

Answer (score 2):

you can use the intuitive [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) class here:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 192,168,1,0 };

    std::ostringstream stream;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); ++i) {
        if (i) stream << '.';
        stream << arr[i];
    }
    std::string string = stream.str();

    std::cout << string << '\n';
}
```

output:

```
192.168.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 192,168,1,0 };
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::string sep = (i < 3) ? "." : "";
        ss << arr[i] << sep;
    }

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

or without conditional

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 192,168,1,0 };
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << arr[0] << "." << arr[1] << "." << arr[2] << "." << arr[3];


    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a string object into which put each elements of the `int` array by adding `.` character after each element except for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of `arr` varies a basic code would be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int arr[]={192,168,1,0};
    std::string output;
    size_t arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
        output.append(std::to_string(arr[i]));
        //skip the last dot .
        if(i != arr_size-1)
            output.append(".");
    }
   std::cout << "output: " << output << std::endl; 
   return 0;
}
```